# Passing parameter without url to Component in Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Is there any way to pass id in Router without mentioning in URL.
Like in following route, Its URL will have a id `abc.com/abc/1`

`<Route exact path="/abc/:vid" component={AbcComponent} />`

I want URL to be `abc.com/abc` and `id` should be available in `AbcComponent`. I tried following but I do not have ids in App.js to pass.

```
<Route exact path="/SpRides" 
render={(props) => <SpRides vid={vid} spId={spId} depId={depId} {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don’t want the id to show up in the url (neither as query string or hash) I think the only solution could be setting it as location state:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

You can set the state value passing the Link "to" prop as an object:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: Yup this works:
I have tried history.push to pass data without mentioning in url. In my App.js I have created a route without any parameter.

```<Route exact path={["/abc"]} component={ComponentAbc} />```

Then from where I was calling the link, I set parameter using history.push

```this.props.history.push({pathname: '/abc', state: { id: 'some_value' }});```

Then in ComponentAbc I received the parameters by accessing location.state

```const parameter = this.props.location.state;```

Comment: This has a flaw that on refresh state became undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a functional approach to solve it:

You can pass "state" prop ( it will push state in history)  in React router Link and then access this in the targeted component using useLocation() hook.

```
<Link to='/abc/' state={{ id:your-id }}>
      click here 
</Link>
```

Now in App.js :

```
<Route exact path="/abc" component={AbcComponent} />
```

and then in AbcComponent file:

```
import { useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

 const AbcComponent= () => {

 const location = useLocation();
 console.log({location });

 return <div> the id is : {location.state.id }</div>;


export default AbcComponent;
```

BONUS:

You can also add as usual [Query params](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters) and access this using useParams() . Just add a state prop in Link. And in AbcComponent , use both useParams() and useLocation() to get the param and state.

Answer (score 0):

Loved the answer given by @S0haib Nasir. Building on that, I used the following solution.

1. In the function component add the code below which would be triggered by the button click

   `props.history.push({pathname: '/abc', state: { id: 'some_value' }})`
2. In the destination component add the following
   `this.props.location.state.id` to access the variable
3. Then use `useEffect` to save the variable in the `localStorage`. This addresses the issue to maintain the state as well in case something goes wrong. Addresses the flaw @S0haib Nasir mentioned as well about the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<Route exact path="/abc/:vid?" component={AbcComponent} />
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)